# payment method integration into sample payment gateway in magento2

Tags: magento2

I've integrated a sample payment gateway module into `Magento 2`.
Now I need to add some payment method in `JS` into a sample payment module. 
so that when the user clicks on place an order a pop appears.

I have a module like an `app/code/Vendor/Module`..

Comment: upload code of your js and .html file

Comment: To which folder path and how to call this method?
magento3\app\code\Iostpay\Iostpaymagento\Model

magento3\app\code\Iostpay\Iostpaymagento\view

Comment: you can't call model method directly from js file you have to call controller and then you can call the model method

Comment: Okay, How can I call a class method on click of place order?

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout_payment.html

this will help you

Comment: More extended version https://www.classyllama.com/blog/how-to-create-payment-method-magento-2

Comment: Thanks for the extended version. i will check this and let you know.

Comment: @RakeshVarma 

Hello, Do you have any idea how can I trigger JS on click of the place order from custom payment gateway.

Comment: add placeOrder function in your payment method js file

Comment: Actually I need to open up a pop-up on click of place order and prevent the submission and check for the payment response then submit with payment response.